# Simulating a Keypress Event from Javascript Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, keypress

I want to simulate a Keypress event using the Javascript Console. I see lots of answers using an input element. I don't want to use an input element. I just want to paste some code into the Javascript console and have a keypress event simulated(specifically the back space button).

Answers using jQuery are welcome.

Comment: Duplicate of [Simulate JavaScript Key Events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events), because triggering the keypress from the browser console or from JavaScript code in a page are equivalent (and forbidden due to security reasons; see the answer on the original question).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

jQuery has a [`.keypress`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/#keypress) method accepting no arguments that simulates a keypress.

```
$("#target").keypress();
```

Will trigger a keypress on `#target`

If you'd like to also select which key was pressed, you can use `.trigger`. This example is from the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/):

```
var e = $.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 8}); //"keydown" if that's what you're doing
$("body").trigger(e);
```

The key code 8 is the [key code for backspace](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) in JavaScript.

Let me know how that works for you :)

Comment: Can you format it so that nothing has to be clicked? I want an easy way to check if different devices have it enabled by pasting the code into console while device is in debug mode.

Comment: Nothing has to be clicked in this answer. You can just put $("#target").keypress(); in your console (presumably, in the end of your pasted code) and it'll trigger a keypress event

Comment: I don't understand what key is being pressed int he example? Don't you need to pass through a number for the specific key?

Comment: This triggers a general keypress, I can edit the answer to let you choose which key was being pressed if you'd like.

Comment: Yes thanks could you edit it to specifically simulate the backbutton being pressed? So I could paste it into the console and simulate someone having hit back space? I know the keycode is 8

Comment: Thanks again I've made a fiddle which I hoped would alert "8" when your code ran. Could you edit it and add to the answer. http://jsfiddle.net/taj8H/3/

Comment: @PhilipK this is because you are attaching an event to keyup and not keydown, see http://jsfiddle.net/EWqfJ/ (or you can change both to keyup)