# Simulate keypress event in Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I want to simulate keypresses in Javascript. There are no listener for those key presses. For example: The function will trigger key '32' (spacebar) and this should result in scrolling of page like pressing normal spacebar.

I tried keypress trigger from [Simulating a Keypress Event from Javascript Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722096/simulating-a-keypress-event-from-javascript-console) but it didn't worked.

**Edit**
Key presses are not limited to spacebar only. It can be combined keys like `alt+Ctrl+D` and the browser should respond to them like keypresses from physical keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only looking to scroll the document, you can approximate a <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> or <kbd>Pg Dn</kbd> scroll by using 85% of `window.innerHeight` - no jQuery needed:

```
window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight * .85);
```

Comment: Scrolling was just an example to illustrate the point. The requirement is general.

Answer (score 0):

By this way you can bind keypress event to body and identify which key is pressed.

```
jQuery('body').on('keyup',function(e){ 
     if(e.which == 32) {
          // spacebar pressed, your scroll code here.
     }
}) ;
```