# Simulated key press function with key code arguments Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress

I'm building a function that simulates keypress events and have adopted the approach from the SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722096/simulating-a-keypress-event-from-javascript-console).

So I wrote this, with the arguments of two key codes and a time when it should trigger.

```
function keypress_sim(key_code1, key_code2, time){
var key = 0;
var rand_proxy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
if(rand_proxy == 1){
    key = key_code1
} else {
    key = key_code2
};
var e = $.Event("keypress",{
    keyCode: key
});
var fire = time;
setTimeout($(document).trigger(e), fire);
$("<div></div>").appendTo('body').text(key);
$("<div></div>").appendTo('body').text(fire);
}

keypress_sim(101,105,100,1500);
```

This does not work as in a) if I put it in an interval, it still only runs once and b) it returns an "unknown identifier" error.
I want this function to be used to "test run" some tasks I wrote in Jquery rather than having to do all keypresses myself.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my function call that should be scheduled by setTimeout executed immediately?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037203/why-is-my-function-call-that-should-be-scheduled-by-settimeout-executed-immediat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
setTimeout($(document).trigger(e), fire);
```

Should be this:

```
setTimeout(function() { $(document).trigger(e) }, fire);
```

The former is calling a function and passing the return value into `setTimeout` as a parameter, the latter is passing `setTimeout` a function as a parameter.